# Default controller used by spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There are multiple controllers provided by spring like

1. ParameterizableViewController
2. UrlFilenameViewController
3. Command Controller

Now when I define a controller bean in spring with annotation @Controller , by default which is controller used by spring internally

Comment: The question is no use. The controller annotation means that your class became a controller so that will be used. With the mentioned 3 controllers you can extend another class to became a controller. In that case no annotation is needed.

Comment: So by annoting the class by  @Controller are we implementing the controller interface, if yes then how the abstract class of controller is implemented

Comment: Annotating in not equal to implementing an interface. If you would like to use Annotations you should use bot: `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` --> First let the framework know that the class can be used as a controller and the second let it know about the mapping you would like to use. More info: [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)